# Calculate length of a shared edge of two polygones in PostGIS

Tags: polygon, postgis

I have a database of several polygones. Each polygon has a lot of nodes which define it. Additionally each polygone has at least one neighbour. For a calculation I need to determine the length of the shared edge of two neighboured polygones. In the example picture such a case is shown. The two polygones share the red edges. How can I calculate the length of the red edge with the help of PostGIS? I didn't find a function for that.

[image: Example of two polygones that share two edges]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the [**intersection**](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) of two polygons, then get the length(s) of any LineStrings. For example, take two geometries:

```
SELECT ST_Length(ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Intersection(a_geom, b_geom), 2))
FROM (
  SELECT
    'POLYGON((70 170,160 250,240 220,270 130,185 62,90 80,70 170))'::geometry AS a_geom,
    'POLYGON((160 250,236 314,380 290,390 150,270 130,240 220,160 250))'::geometry AS b_geom
) f;
```

Or do this for all pairs of polygons in a table `mypoly` that [**touch**](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Touches.html):

```
SELECT a.gid AS gid_a, b.gid AS gid_b,
  ST_Length(ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom), 2))
FROM mypoly a, mypoly b
WHERE a.gid < b.gid AND ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom);
```

You can also explore the [Topology extension](http://postgis.net/docs/Topology.html), which is part of PostGIS 2.x.